# .change() with multiple fields fires for each changed field out of focus

Tags: jquery

How can I get .change() with the multiple selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”) to fire once all of the fields are out of focus, instead of each time one of the changed fields becomes out of focus?

thanks!

Comment: You want something to happen on `change` ONLY if no given element is focused?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Right! When user has completed the form (and unfocused all the fields), I want something to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `change` event **and** the `blur` event.

In the below example, all fields will turn red **on blur** of one of them, if there is none of them beeing focussed **and** if at least one of them as changed.

```js
var inputChanged = false;

$(".test").on("change", function(){
  inputChanged = true;
});
  
$(".test").on("blur", function(){
  var flag=true;

  setTimeout(function(){
  
    // Check if one input is focussed 10 ms after that blur.
    $(".test").each(function(){
      if( $(this).is(":focus") ){
        flag = false;
      }
    });

    // If no input focussed and at least one input changed.
    if(flag && inputChanged){
      $(".test").css({"background-color":"red"});
    }
  },10);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="test"><br>
<input class="test"><br>
<input class="test"><br>
```

Comment: I have some issues with this code :S the code won't work if the user inputs something in the first field than presses "tab" three times to exit the form

Comment: You want to check if all inputs are filled ?

Comment: no no, I just want a .change() event but for all fields at the same time.  
Let me explain: If at least one field is changed, as soon as all the field are out of focus, I want all fields to turn red.  The issue with your code is that it only checks if the last field that was focused was changed.

Comment: With your code, if I change the first field, than click on the second field, than click outside the form, the fields won't turn red.

Comment: Ok... I see. Hold on.

Comment: There it is... ;) You also need the blur event. ;)